# Is there a way to prevent browsers from caching values like scroll position and zoom level?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, browser-cache

I am designing an interactive web game that takes place entirely in the browser. It uses html5, and everything (including the elements) is part of the game world. Since this is the case, I need some pretty strict control over the positioning of my elements, scroll position, zooming, etc.

One particular level requires that an element be placed off screen (just outside the viewport) so that the user must scroll the page to find it. Unfortunately, after scrolling, the page seems to record the new width of the page including the originally unseen element. When the page is refreshed, the zoom level is adjusted to fit the entire screen with the hidden element into the viewport. This gives away the puzzle and ruins the level.

I know that browsers store information like scroll position so that when a user revisits the page they can pick up right where they left off. This is great for some things, but bad for my purposes. Is there a way to prevent this caching behavior of my browsers? Is there a way to get or set the zoom level of a page using JavaScript?

Currently I am using the code below to reset the scroll position right before the user leaves the page. It works pretty well, but the user can see the page scroll right before leaving.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function(event_){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    /* What I would love is if there were a way to do this: */
    // window.zoomTo(1.0);
    /* But I'm sure that's asking for too much. */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by keeping the hidden element out of the html flow all together by setting its css `position` property to `fixed`. I simulate page scrolling by changing the elements `style.left` value with some custom touch event handlers. The page has no need to resize or zoom with the addition of the off screen element because fixed position elements do not effect layout.

This doesn't answer my question about resetting the zoom level, however, and I would still appreciate any insight anyone may have.